# Pegar dados específicos do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Bom galera, estou fazendo um projeto com as seguintes páginas `pedidos.php` e `anexa.php`. O action dos pedidos vai para a página anexa, nela tenho o envio do conteúdo para o banco de dados e e-mail, através da função `mail()`, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Porém, desejo em outra página, chamada "Meus pedidos", exibir os dados do pedido realizado.

Mas não sei como fazer essa inclusão especifica, todo os pedidos vão para o mesmo banco, e de pessoas diferentes que realizam o login.

Alguém me ajuda com essa dúvida! Por favor! Desde Já agradeço.

**Página anexa.php**

```
<?php
    $nome        = $_POST['nome_empresa'];
    $telefone    = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];
    $material    = $_POST['material'];
    $cor         = $_POST['cor'];
    $quantidade  = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $acabamento  = $_POST['acabamento'];
    $formato     = $_POST['formato'];
    $altura      = $_POST['altura'];
    $largura     = $_POST['largura'];
    $papel       = $_POST['papel'];
    $gramatura   = $_POST['gramatura'];
    $descricao   = $_POST['descricao'];
    $aleatorio=rand(1,99999);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos (nome_empresa, telefone, email, material, cor, quantidade, acabamento, formato, altura, largura, papel, gramatura, descricao, aleatorio) VALUES ('$nome', '$telefone', '$email', '$material', '$cor', '$quantidade', '$acabamento', '$formato', '$altura', '$largura', '$papel', '$gramatura', '$descricao', '$aleatorio')");
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <?php
        include ("Mail.php");
        include ("Mail/mime.php");

        $up=0;

        $nome        = $_POST['nome_empresa'];
        $telefone    = $_POST['telefone'];
        $email       = $_POST['email'];
        $material    = $_POST['material'];
        $cor         = $_POST['cor'];
        $quantidade  = $_POST['quantidade'];
        $acabamento  = $_POST['acabamento'];
        $formato     = $_POST['formato'];
        $altura      = $_POST['altura'];
        $largura     = $_POST['largura'];
        $papel       = $_POST['papel'];
        $gramatura   = $_POST['gramatura'];
        $descricao   = $_POST['descricao'];

        $recipients = 'contato@conexaografica.com.br';

        $headers = array (
            'From'    => 'contato@conexaografica.com.br', 
            'To'      => $recipients,
            'Subject' => "Pedido N#$aleatorio"
        );

        $crlf = "\r\n";
        $text = "<p>Um novo pedido foi realizado por: $nome</p></br></br>

            DETALHES DO PEDIDO:</br></br>

            Pedido de Numero:#$aleatorio</br>
            Telefone: $telefone</br>
            Email: $email</br>
            ____________________________________</br></br>

            Material: $material</br>
            Acabamento: $acabamento</br>
            Formato: $formato</br>
            Tamanho = $altura x $largura</br>
            Cor: $cor</br>
            Papel : $papel</br>
            Gramatura: $gramatura</br>
            Quantidade: $quantidade</br></br>

            Descricoes: $descricao
        ";

        $html = "<HTML><BODY><font color=blue>$text</font></BODY></HTML>";

        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

        for( $i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['anexo']['name']); $i++ ) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
                $caminho[$i] = "/home/conexaografica/www/areaderevendedor/tmp/".$_FILES['anexo']['name'][$i];

                if(copy($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i],$caminho[$i])) {
                    $mime->addAttachment($caminho[$i]);
                    unlink($caminho[$i]);
                    echo "Seu arquivo foi anexado!<br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<h1>O arquivo não foi transferido!</h1>";
                echo "<h2><font color='red'>Caminho ou nome de arquivo Inválido</font></h2>";
            }
        }

        $body = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

        $params = array (
            'auth' => true, 
            'host' => 'smtp.conexaografica.com.br',
            'username' => 'contato=conexaografica.com.br',
            'password' => 'conexaografica' 
        );

        $mail_object = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
        $result = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
        if (PEAR::IsError($result)) {
            echo "Algo deu errado... (" . $result->getMessage(). ")";
        } else {
            echo(
                "<P>$nome, Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso.</P>".
                "Pedido de Numero:#$aleatorio <br>".         
                "<P align='center'>DETALHES DO PEDIDO:</P>".
                "Telefone: $telefone <br>".
                "Email: $email <br>".
                "<P>____________________________________</P>".
                "Material: $material <br>".
                "Acabamento: $acabamento <br>".
                "Formato: $formato <br>".
                "Tamanho = $altura x $largura <br>".
                "Cor: $cor <br>".
                "Papel : $papel <br>".
                "Gramatura: $gramatura <br>".
                "Quantidade: $quantidade <br><br>".

                "OBS: Salve o numero do seu pedido."
            );
        }   
    ?>

    </br></br>

    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $date = date('H:i d/m/Y');
        echo ("Hora e Data: $date");
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Página login.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login"){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        if(empty($usuario) || empty($senha)){
            echo 'Preencha todos os campos!';
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT nome, usuario, senha FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $busca = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            if($busca > 0){
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $linha['usuario'];
                header('Location: logado.php');
                exit;
            }else{
                echo 'Usuário ou senha inválidos.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Página pedidos.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("settings/setting.php");
    @session_start();

    $nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['nome']) && !isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Dica: Selecionar todo o código e clicar **`Ctrl + K`** deixa ele formatado.

Comment: Qual é o script de login ?

Comment: coloquei como resposta!

Comment: Ok, já foi excluída, sou novo no site, não sabia com funciona as coisas ainda!

Comment: Normal :) aproveite para fazer um [tour] e ver as paginas de [faq]

Comment: `pedidos` está de alguma forma relacionado com o usuário ?

Comment: Bom, editei a pergunta com o topo do pedidos.php.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente: nunca, nunca, nunca, nunca, nunca, nunca coloque variáveis não tratadas nas suas queries pro banco de dados. Nunca. Jamais. Isso é pedir pra ter seu sistema hackeado por crianças. [Use essa função para evitar esse problema](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Agora, seu problema principal é que você não está usando seu banco de dados direito. Você quer listar os pedidos realizados pelo usuário que está logado, correto? Então você precisa incluir a chave primária (o ID) do usuário nos seus pedidos. Crie uma coluna para guardar a chave do usuário na hora que ele faz o pedido e depois é só fazer um `SELECT` pelo id de usuário logado. Algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE usuario_id = $usuario_id
```

Nesse caso nem precisaria tratar, pois você já tratou no login, mas trate assim mesmo. Ah! E você vai precisar colocar o id do usuário na sua `SESSION` também, claro.